# Differing results from gv$session

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-se, oracle-rac

The following query returns no results, yet it seems like it should.

```
SELECT * FROM gv$session where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
```

In my 11.2.0.2 Standard Edition RAC environment the above query returns no results, yet the following variations all return results.

```
SELECT sid FROM gv$session where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');

SELECT * FROM gv$session where SID = 256; --Your SID will likely be different.

SELECT * FROM v$session where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
```

Can anyone confirm this behavior and/or explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got following results

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') FROM DUAL;
-- 5276 

SELECT * FROM gv$session where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
-- No result

SELECT * FROM gv$session where SID =5276;
-- 4 results for 4 node RAC
-- 1 result matches my USERNAME,OSUSER, MACHINE and PROGRAM
-- 3 results are different from my USERNAME,OSUSER, MACHINE and PROGRAM

SELECT * FROM v$session where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
-- 1 result
```

I cannot explain but following query in 4 node RAC gives interesting output.

```
SELECT '1' AS QUERY_NUMBER,S.* FROM gv$session S where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
UNION ALL
SELECT '2',S.* FROM gv$session S where SID = ( SELECT  SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') FROM DUAL)
UNION ALL
SELECT '3',-1,S.* FROM v$session S where SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
```

QUERY_NUMBER = 1, no rows

QUERY_NUMBER = 2, 4 rows (4 node RAC)

QUERY_NUMBER = 3, 1 row

Comment: Thanks for verifying my findings.  I am seeing the same behavior except that I don't always get multiple results for the SID=5276 variety, but I sometimes do.  Nesting SYS_CONTEXT in a sub-select is interesting.  It means that when the function is called only once it returns results, but when it is run for every row of the results it does not.  They get different plans, so something is happening incorrectly it would seem.